# Jahia : unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM

Tags: maven, maven-2, pom.xml, jahia

I am trying to create module from Jahia Studio and getting below error.

```
  Non-resolvable parent POM for org.jahia.modules:news:2.0.4: 
  Could not transfer artifact org.jahia.modules:jahia-modules:pom:7.0.0.0 from/to jahia-public (https://devtools.jahia.com/nexus/content/groups/public): 
  sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: 
  unable to find valid certification path to requested target and 'parent.relativePath' points at wrong local POM @ line 49, column 11 -> [Help 2]
```

Using Jahia CommunityDistribution 7.3.4.1 SDK and Maven version 3.6.3

When Trying to run mvn clean install getting above error everytime.

Comment: Did you try to get the code from https://github.com/Jahia/news/releases/tag/2_0_4 and compile it on your side?

Comment: Yes I tried , same error as mentioned above.

Comment: What JDK version do you use?

Comment: @PhilippeVollenweider C:\Jahia-CommunityDistribution-7.3.4.1-SDK\Jahia-CE-7.3.4.1-SDK\sources\news>mvn -v
Apache Maven 3.6.3 (cecedd343002696d0abb50b32b541b8a6ba2883f)
Maven home: C:\Program Files\apache-maven-3.6.3\bin\..
Java version: 1.8.0_66, vendor: Oracle Corporation, runtime: C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_66\jre
Default locale: en_IN, platform encoding: Cp1252
OS name: "windows 10", version: "10.0", arch: "amd64", family: "windows"

Comment: I think you should have a JDK >= 8u101 (see https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/ )

Comment: @PhilippeVollenweider Thanks you so much for your quick and accurate help. Kindly answer the question so I can upvote. So as a solution I have installed latest JDK and it solved my issue as per your suggestion :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As https://devtools.jahia.com/nexus/content/groups/public use a Let's Encrypt SSL certificate, you should have a JDK >= 8u101. See the [certificate-compatibility](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/certificate-compatibility/) page